# Правильно ли расставлены запятые? 2

Tags: пунктуация

Лехе, дайте, он съест это сразу и виду не подаст.

Comment: Николай, на сайте принято благодарить участников за полезные ответы стрелочкой (треугольником) вверх, а также принимать один из них галочкой, как принятый.

Answer (score 1):

**Лёхе дайте, он съест это сразу и виду не подаст.**
Это сложное бессоюзное предложение, между его частями ставится запятая.
*Лёхе дайте* — односоставное (определённо-личное) предложение, [Вы] *дайте* — сказуемое.
*Он съест это сразу и виду не подаст* — двусоставное предложение; *он* — подлежащее, *съест, виду не подаст* — однородные сказуемые (в этом случае перед союзом "и" запятая не ставится).
[Не подавать виду](https://phraseology.academic.ru/8753/%D0%9D%D0%B5_%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C_%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%B4%D1%83) — фразеологизм.

Для обозначения смысловой паузы вместо запятой можно поставить тире.

*— Кому отдать-то, чтобы никто ничего не заметил?

— **Лёхе дайте — он съест это сразу и виду не подаст.***

[Бессоюзное сложное предложение](https://obrazovaka.ru/russkiy-yazyk/bessoyuznoe-slozhnoe-predlozhenie.html)
[Односоставное определённо-личное предложение](https://obrazovaka.ru/russkiy-yazyk/odnosostavnoe-opredelenno-lichnoe-predlozhenie-primery.html)

В зависимости от контекста вполне возможны и другие пунктуационные варианты.
Например: *Лёхе дайте: он съест это сразу. И виду не подаст!*